# Is it possible to execute_script with Ruby's selenium-webdriver while page starts to load

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium

I am trying to make javascript execute while loading

I am trying to achieve an effect that can be achieved if script would make following change

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.screen.__defineGetter__('width', function(){return 1024;});
    window.screen.__defineGetter__('height', function(){return 768;});
</script>
```

However, I cannot put this javascript inside a page, they have to be coming from Ruby, there are other things I might add other than `window.width` and `window.screen`

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
driver.execute_script("window.screen.__defineGetter__('height', function(){return 768;});") # this executes before page load starts
driver.navigate.to 'http://somesite.com/'
driver.execute_script("window.screen.__defineGetter__('height', function(){return 768;});") # this executes after page completely loads
```

So, what I want to do is to execute for example

`driver.execute_script("window.screen.__defineGetter__('height', function(){return 768;});")`

this while page loads, it does not work if I put this before `navigate.to` or after `navigate.to`. The same is if I change `.navigate.to` with `.get`

Comment: Doesn't work means what? any error?

Comment: No, no errors, just no effect. Imagine going to site1.com, setting window.screen to foo, then going to site2.com, window.screen will not be foo. This is the case. I want an execution to happen right on document load, not after it finishes loading as I use window.screen inside a document as on any ordinary page, not after document finished to load.

Comment: why `driver.execute_script('')` is empty ? I am just trying to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Suppose page has a script `window.load = function(){ alert(window.screen.width); }` I want to change this value which can be done by `window.screen.__defineGetter__('width', function(){return 1024;});` However, in my attempts, selenium executes this script either before a request to site is made, or after a request is done. P.S. those values were empty to indicate any code can go there and there's no effect if executed data will be processed during a page load.

Comment: Humm,I am getting error as an *invalid javascript*.

Comment: Let's say we execute `driver.execute_script('alert("I AM HERE")');` before and after `driver.navigate.to 'http://somesite.com/'` then, first alert will appear before request, ie, blank screen, another when page completely loads, ie, process is done. This is not right for me. I want alert to appear, say, in a middle, before,..um. say before google analytics code gets executed.

Comment: i got your point,but why I am getting error I don't know! :(

Comment: You need to use Thread! I think :)

Comment: I have tried threads since I am also interested but it failed with `error: closed stream` message. Here's a gist https://gist.github.com/dnatsvlishvili/6486391

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not going to work. The reason is quite simple, anything that you inject before `navigate.to` is going to be executed on different page than your target page. Anything that you inject after `navigate.to` will most likely be executed after your application is started.

If you would like to get specific window size, you can set it before you navigate to the page: 
`driver.manage.window.resize_to("1024", "768")` (for chrome browser)
or create a separate Firefox profile, with predefined window width and height and use it in your tests.